# Nested list of objects not getting deserialized in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a /reports api that returns an output like :

```
 {
  "data": {
    "id": 87,
    "type": "reports",
    "attributes": {
      "status": "STARTED",
      "startdatetime": 1532511531000,
      "enddatetime": 1533485380052,
      "queries": [
       {
        "startdatetime": 1532511531000,
        "enddatetime": 1533485380056,
        "reportId": 87,
        "id": "Q1"
      }
    ]
   }
  }
}
```

The models looks like:

model/report.js

```
status: DS.attr('string'),
startdatetime: DS.attr('number'),
enddatetime: DS.attr('number'),
queries: DS.hasMany('query')
```

model/query.js :

```
report : DS.belongsTo('report'),
startdatetime: DS.attr('number'),
enddatetime: DS.attr('number')
```

In my component (template.js), I try to access the queries and it seems to not be able to deserialize it right :

```
queriesLength: Ember.computed('report', function(){
  return this.get('report').get('queries').length;
}
```

Running queriesLength() returns 0 for the above mentioned json.

1) There are no issues in the console.log.

2) The browser network shows that the api returned the output correctly.

3) When accessing other properties like startdatetime, it returns the right value.

Is the model/api response missing something?

Comment: your response is not JSON:APi complient. Relationships should be under `relationships` not `attributes`, and then the related data should be under the `data` key and then again a JSON:API Resource Object, so there should be a `type` and the attributes under `attributes`. Either modify your server response or your serializer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ember Data uses the `JSONAPI` serializer. When the data from other models is included in the data of the response, it's called an `embedded record`.

If you have control over the backend, switch to using the JSONAPI spec of included relationships. If you don't,

Switch to using the `DS.RestSerializer` and the Embedded Records Mixin:

https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin

Create a new serializer with a generator `ember generate serializer report`

```
// serializers/report.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    queries: { embedded: 'always' },
  }
});
```